# AngularJs - Disable input on table dependent upon top row selection

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I am trying to make a tables input elements disabled from below the top (master) row if the "Active" or "Engaged" boolean is set to true on the top row. I do not want them to loose their data below the top row when they set it true, only to disable it. If the user sets the "Active" && "Engaged" to false on the top row then I want them to be able to edit the data below the top row again. Is there an easy way to do this with AngularJs?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/7kg6kuzm/2/

```
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<p>{{test}}</p>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="border-less"></th>
            <th>People</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Engaged</th>
            <th>Town</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(month, info) in months">
            <td><p>{{month}}</p></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="info.people"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="info.active"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="info.engaged"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="info.form" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

possible json object value (in this case since the "all" or top row has one of the booleans set to true the rest of the rows would be disabled):

```
var months = {
  "all": {"people":25,"active":true,"engaged":false,"form":"test0"},
  "jan": {"people":63,"active":false,"engaged":true,"form":"test2"},
  "feb": {"people":46,"active":true,"engaged":false,"form":"test3"},
  "mar": {"people":65,"active":false,"engaged":false,"form":"test4"},
  "apr": {"people":66,"active":true,"engaged":true,"form":"test5"},
  "may": {"people":67,"active":false,"engaged":true,"form":"test6"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, putting for future reference or if anybody else needs to know how to do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/7kg6kuzm/3/

I ended up putting a check on each input line and also checking the value of the first line:

```
<td><input ng-disabled="(months['all'].active || months['all'].engaged) && this.month!=='all'" type="text" ng-model="info.people"/></td>
```